# Document can't "Save As" on mac after appending certain documents in a word doc via C#

Tags: c#, windows, macos, ms-word, openxml-sdk

The behavior is as follows:  After downloading a document that is dynamically created on the server and then opening that document up on a Mac, the document will not "Save As".  It fails silently, setting the document name to the previous name, and no document in the save destination folder.

Under the hood: The code creates the document and appends text and then at the end of that file it appends word documents that are uploaded by another person for that created document.  The code is using the `AltChunk` class as outlined in the MSDN documents [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=openxml-2.8.1).  This works well and there aren't much issues except, intermittently, with certain attachments as described above.

This APPEARS to be a bug with word and I'm not sure if there's anything on my part that can be done until this bug is patched in word or in OpenXML.

## Code to Reproduce Below

The following below are the steps needed to reproduce this bug:

1. Create a new Console App in Visual Studio on Mac
2. Add a folder to the top level called "Docs"
3. Download the Nuget dependency `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`
4. Create a new word doc named "test-source.docx"

   1. Put some test text in there, doesn't matter what
   2. Add the document to the solution in "Docs" folder
   3. Change the property to "Copy always"
5. Create a new word doc named "test-append.docx" (the embedded word doc)

   1. Put in some test text at the top
   2. Copy over a jpg of your choice.  The image type I used to reproduce is a jpg.  I fetched mine from http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ , one of their big pics should do it.
   3. Add to the "Docs" folder in the solution
   4. Change property of document to "Copy always"
6. Copy paste the code below into your `Program.cs` file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using Text = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text;

namespace TestWordAppend
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var destinationDoc = "Docs/test-destination.docx";
            var sourceDoc = "Docs/test-source.docx";
            var appendedDoc = "Docs/test-append2.docx";

            File.Delete(destinationDoc);
            File.Copy(sourceDoc, destinationDoc);

            using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationDoc, true))
            {
                var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

                var p2 = body.InsertAfter(
                    new Paragraph(
                        new ParagraphProperties(
                            new PageBreakBefore()
                    )),
                    body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last()
                );


                var altChunkId = "AltChunkId";
                var chunk = doc.MainDocumentPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML,
                    altChunkId);

                using (var fs = File.Open(appendedDoc, FileMode.Open))
                    chunk.FeedData(fs);

                var altChunk = new AltChunk { Id = altChunkId };
                var run = new Run(new TabChar(), new Text(appendedDoc), new Break());
                run.PrependChild(new RunProperties { RunStyle = new RunStyle { Val = "Bold" } });
                var fileP = p2.InsertAfterSelf(new Paragraph());
                fileP.Append(run);
                run = new Run(new TabChar(), new Text("Uploaded by: "), new TabChar(), new Text("Test User"));
                run.PrependChild(new RunProperties { RunStyle = new RunStyle { Val = "Italic" } });
                fileP.Append(run);

                body.Append(altChunk);
                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Run it
2. Check the document in `~/bin/Debug/netcoreapp.3.0/Docs/test-destination.docx` where `~` is the base path the solution is located.
3. Open it up and try and do a "Save As" in your `~/Documents` folder where `~` is your user's home path.
4. It should not save, in fact it should revert back to the name "test-destination.docx".  When you check your documents folder, you will not see a new document there.

Comment: But it works in Windows? What, more specifically, is in this content being "appended"? Without more information or a way to reproduce there's really not much anyone here can contribute.

Comment: @CindyMeister - thank you for answering, I appreciate it.  As a quick note, it is *not* reproducible on windows.  I'm currently working on a console app on asp.net core 3 to reproduce the issue as a stand alone application away from proprietary work.  I will then try to see if I can get a generic document from the offending document (scrubbed) to use so that it can be reproducible on any mac.  If I achieve this, I will update my question.

Comment: I'd look closely at the content from the documents being added via altChunk - anything unusual (not "plain text") they contain. Also, if there's a pattern in the version of Word (both OS as well as numeric version) where they're being created. I'd suspect they may contain something not "known" to a Mac...

Comment: There are pictures in the document.  When I created a new document with embedded pictures to test to see if this is the cause, I was not able to reproduce.  It may have something to do with the pictures but why?  They are viewable in the word doc on mac, the doc in mac looks fine, you just can't "Save As".

Comment: Otherwise, there's nothing else I see as fishy.  Just text and bullet points.

Comment: I was able to successfully recreate the problem with a generic docx, all on mac, by using a simple jpg that I embedded.  I will update my answer.

Comment: @CindyMeister - I have updated my answer with a full working example.  If you or anyone need the original documents I used, I can see if I can setup a download place somewhere, but I think you can reproduce it with a jpg from apod.

Comment: apod? or iPod? I would have an iPhone or iPad: any idea if those formats are also a problem?

Comment: @CindyMeister - I mention "apod" as in "Astronomical Picture of the Day" as a resource to download an image from to embed in the appending word document.  I used these pictures in my testing and was able to reproduce so I mentioned it.  As far as iPhone or iPad, I don't have any issues there.  We don't use the phone for word docs so I'm not sure what would be affected there.  This is primarily a concern on the MacOS for word using OpenXML as the server code to generate the document with.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that could help mitigate this problem but I think it's just a workaround.  I've posted this bug to OpenXML.  I'm not sure if it is in fact OpenXML's issue, seems it may be Word instead, but at least the issue is raised and noted somewhere.

Otherwise I've resorted to finding this solution below.  Instead I have to go through each element and clone it and then append it to the source document. 
 If there are images in the cloned element, I have to do some extra steps for the image to copy over to the new document.

```cs
private static void GenerateByCopying()
{
    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DestinationDoc, true))
    using (var appendedDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(AppendedDoc, true))
    {
        var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        var appendedBody = appendedDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        AppendNecessaryText(body);

        foreach (var part in appendedBody.Elements())
        {
            var clonedElement = part.CloneNode(true);
            clonedElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(imageData =>
                {
                    var newRelation = CopyImage(doc, imageData.Embed, appendedDoc);
                    imageData.Embed = newRelation;

                });
            clonedElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.ImageData>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(imageData =>
                {
                    var newRelation = CopyImage(doc, imageData.RelationshipId, appendedDoc);
                    imageData.RelationshipId = newRelation;
                });
            body.Append(clonedElement);
        }

        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }
}

public static string CopyImage(WordprocessingDocument doc, string relId, WordprocessingDocument source)
{
    var p = source.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(relId) as ImagePart;
    var np = doc.MainDocumentPart.AddPart(p);
    np.FeedData(p.GetStream());
    return doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(np);
}
```

Adjusting the console app run this method after `File.Copy()`, I'm indeed able to open the document with the image and save changes.